# How to parse mail title from mail inbox not Chinese incorrect codes

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am doing parsing the mail from mail inbox using `java`, the content of mail is correct, but there is a error that the mail title is Chinese incorrect codes. the code : `subject = message.getSubject();` the `subject` has some Chinese incorrect codes.

there are some codes as below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", mailProtocol.getProtocol());
props.setProperty(mailProtocol.getHostName(), mailProtocol.getHost());
props.setProperty(mailProtocol.getPortName(), mailProtocol.getPort());
String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect(cVMailbox.getBoxUserName(), pwd);

Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
for (int i = folder.getMessageCount(); i > 1; i--) {

    Message message = folder.getMessage(i);
     MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage)message;
    sentDate = message.getSentDate();

     subject = message.getSubject();

}
```

How to get the correct mail title? anyone can help me?

Comment: can you please paste output of subject and expected as well? can you see it properly on mail client ?

Comment: yes, it is correct on mail client. but when i use java to parse the mail title from mail inbox, it has some Chinese incorrect codes!

Comment: If you use msg.getHeader("Subject"), what do you get?  If the header is MIME encoded but contains incorrect characters or the wrong charset name, you can try to decode it yourself.  It depends on exactly how the Subject data is wrong to know the best approach for working around the problem.

Comment: @BillShannon i have used msg.getHeader("Subject"), it still has that error!

Comment: Right, it wasn't supposed to fix the problem.  It was supposed to give us enough data to understand exactly what the problem is.  Can you post the output?

Answer (score 1):

Before session initialisation put below code :

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.decodetext.strict", "false");
```

and then try below code :

```
String subject = MimeUtility.decodeText(message.getSubject());
```

Comment: could you plz post incorrect output and expected output

Comment: Thank u very much, your answer helps me!

Comment: if only use your code, it doesn't solve my question. the message should be replaced by GBK. i have changed the code:
'String[] strMailSubject = msg.getHeader("subject");
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (String str : strMailSubject) {
            
         stringBuffer.append(str.replaceAll("gb2312","GBK").replaceAll("GB2312","GBK")); // convert x-unkown to gbk
        }
        subject = MimeUtility.decodeText(stringBuffer.toString());'

Comment: that's data issue and nothing to do with encoding, posting data in question  sometimes useful for providing solution.